# URL Bar id=1 Into jQuery ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

i want to get the id from the url bar and insert it into the href

$("a[href='send_message.php?act=pm&id=$id']").colorbox({width:"500", height:"350", iframe:true});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's a jquery plugin to make this ridiculously simple:

see: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object

e.g.

```
var id = $.query.get('id');
$("a[href='send_message.php?act=pm&id="+id+"']").colorbox({width:"500", height:"350", iframe:true});
```

Answer (score 1):

For those not using jQuery or any other JS library:

```
var searchString = document.location.search;  

// strip off the leading '?'
searchString = searchString.substring(1);

var gvPairs = searchString.split("&");
var getVars = [];

for (i = 0; i < gvPairs.length; i++)
{
    var gvPair = gvPairs[i].split("=");
    getVars[gvPair[0]] = gvPair[1];
}
```

So if the URL string was index.php?id=3&page=2&display=10 then:
    `getVars['id'] = 3;`
    `getVars['page'] = 2;`
    `getVars['display'] = 10;`

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `var getVars = []`